# Spring get response as json to object casting

Tags: java, spring

When i go (hit URL in the browser) to some URL
I got a json response matching my Class fields (GET RESPONSE).

I want to converter this json to my object without using some Java converters like jackson.

What spring annotation could i use here?

What i try to do is something like that, so it automatically translates json to object:

```
@RequestMapping("/getCar") 
public Car getCar(@SOMEANNOTATION(Car car) 
{ return car;}
```

Comment: How do you "go" to a url?

Comment: Spring needs a MessageConverter in order to convert your response to Json and viceversa. Without that, I don't think you can convert an object directly. There is also `org.json` which lets you convert json to object. You may check that.

Comment: @JohnnyAW I hit the URL in the browser

Comment: @v1shnu this is what i ask for - some fast way of converting `json` -> `object` not like `Fatima Khan` answer

Comment: Is your application not intended to use any Json converters?

Comment: @v1shnu just looking for some other way. I know that i can do that with `jackson` but i am looking for faster option

Comment: Jackson is actually faster. What makes you say Jackson is not faster?

Comment: @v1shnu i meant lines of code number

Comment: Jackson only uses two line to convert your Json to object. One is to initialize the Object mapper and other is to parse the line. Nothing more. I think that is the best option possible.

Comment: @v1shnu thanks for your opinion - still you need to provide `json` for `jackson` with code somehow - will that be in the second line (without some long text)?

Comment: If you are hitting the url like JohnnyAW's answer, then you just have to add Jackson to the http message converter. Spring will automatically convert the response string to the java class without you having to do it explicitly. I think it would be better if you post a little of your code. Maybe we can help better.

Comment: Hey just saw your question. You should use @RequestBody annotation. That way Spring will use its message converter to parse the Json that you are sending to the Car object.

Comment: Please check my answer below and tell me if that achieves what you are trying to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using RestTemplate:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Car car = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/getCar", Car.class);
```

you need a Class car, so Spring can map it:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Car {
    ...
}
```

but you need to understand, that Spring will still use some converter under the hood to create/read the data...

Comment: you're welcome, i didn't test it, so use with care, maybe there is something new in new version of Spring...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this @Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml" })

Comment: I am not sure if he is talking about service or handling data in client after hitting a url

Comment: I meant hitting URL in the browser

Comment: @FatimaKhan will this allow to directly convert from `json` to needed class object when handling `get` response?

Comment: @yami yes i think so                                                                                        ===>@GET
 @Path("/users/{id}")
 @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
 @PreAuthorize("@urprojectname.isAPIAccessible(\"" + LIST.GET_YOURUSER + "\")")
 public ClassObject method(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
  return class.method(id);
 }

Comment: @FatimaKhan your example is wrong - i do not want something from the `url` like `id` but take json from the `response` and translate it to specific class object. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @yami I think you misunderstand something. In the scenario you provided, Spring doesn't convert json -> Object, but rather object -> json. Your client (Browser in your case) is now responsible to process this json generated by Spring.

Comment: @JohnnyAW i meant scenario when you visit a URL for example:
localhost:8080/getCar - you get `json` response by `HTTP GET` that i want to bind in `Spring` to `Car` object and this is the scenario i provided. Nothing changed. And it does not matter how the `json` on that page is produced - this is not the concern.

Comment: @yami if you call `getCar` **in your browser**, Spring will be only responsible to server the json. Do you want to consume this url by something like a `RestTemplate`? If you only want to use your browser (like you said in the question) Spring has nothing to do with json processing in this case!

Comment: @JohnnyAW - 1. true 
2. Yes - i want to consume this url, so we can write in `Spring` if `/getCar` is hit then convert `json` response of that `GET` to `Car` object and return it.

Comment: @JohnnyAW in the question i only mentioned that when i hit this `URL` i get this `json` already - and next i wrote what i want to do.

Comment: @yami ok, now what do you use to get the data from the url? `RestTemplate` or something else?

Comment: @JohnnyAW i thought if i can write something like (that automatically translates `json` to `object`):

@RequestMapping("/getCar")
    public Car gerCar(@SOMEANNOTATION(Car car) {
return car}

Comment: @yami   ==>@POST @Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml" })@Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" }) public urClass create(urClass obj,@Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
                return classname.methodName(obj);
 }

Comment: @FatimaKhan question was about `GET` not `POST`

Comment: @FatimaKhan yes - and the question is how to translate that output into object of specific class like CAR  via GET

Answer (score 1):

There's another solution from Sring Boot documentation **[Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)**.

Basically, the serialization/deserialization of the object is handled automatically by Spring converter. In other word, **you have nothing to do in this case**.

Consider a basic REST controller :

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

> The `Greeting` object must be converted to JSON. Thanks to Spring’s HTTP
>   message converter support, you don’t need to do this conversion
>   manually. Because **[Jackson 2](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)** is on the classpath, Spring’s
>   [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) is automatically chosen to convert
>   the `Greeting` instance to JSON.

Comment: Why we need here `@RequestParam` ? My `URL` does not contain any parameters.

And i want to convert from `JSON` to `OBJECT` not the other way.

Comment: This is an example from the documentation. Feel free to adapt this example to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this to automatically convert your request body json to a Java Object.

```
@RequestMapping("/getCar", method =RequestMethod.POST,
produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public Car getCar(@RequestBody Car car){
    return car;
}
```

However, Spring will use an HttpMessageConverter at the backend to convert your json request to a POJO. Something like this should be added to your `@Configuration` class

```
public void configureMessageConverters() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

Comment: Hey, it does not achieve my goal cause the difficulty is that is should work on `GET`. Does This code also work on `GET`?

I knew if i used `POST` i could do that what you wrote down.

Comment: In Get method, you can't have a controller method which takes in an argument. In your question, you have it like this `public Car getCar(@SOMEANNOTATION(Car car) ` Here the Car argument will not work for Get since get does not have a request body.Only POST and PUT can take in request body.

Comment: yeah, so i am looking what else can i do for `GET`
Thanks for valuable comment

Comment: In GET you can only pass RequestParam. What exactly does your getCar method intend to do ?

Comment: i just got a question if I can do something similiar as you wrote here for `POST` method - and i am looking for an answer. As i read myself - then i knew that `RequestParam` or `respondeBody` was no good here - so i posted question here - looking for alternatives apart from `jackson` which i knew.